# Calculate limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(4n-100)^{4n-100}n^n}{(3n)^{3n}(2n)^{2n}}?$

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

The limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(4n)^{4n}n^n}{(3n)^{3n}(2n)^{2n}}$$ can be calculated as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{4^{4n}}{3^{3n}2^{2n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{4^4}{3^32^2}\right)^n=\infty$.

What about $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(4n-100)^{4n-100}n^n}{(3n)^{3n}(2n)^{2n}}?$$ Would it still be $\infty$?

Comment: **Hint**: Factor $4n$ forcefully outside the parenthesis, and see what you get. :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian What do you mean by "forcefully"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your function $f(n)$.  Then it's enough to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log f(n) = \infty$.  We can write

$\log f(n) = (4n-100) \log (4n-100) + n \log n - 2n \log 2n - 3n \log 3n$

and let's consider that first term, $(4n-100) \log (4n-100)$.  It would be really nice if that were $4n \log 4n$, so let's rewrite it as

$(4n-100) \log (4n-100) = (4n-100) \log 4n + (4n-100) \log ((4n-100)/4n)$

or, after some rearrangement,

$4n \log 4n - 100 \log 4n + (4n-100) \log (1 - 25/n)$.

Therefore the original function is

$\log f(n) = (4n \log 4n + n \log n - 2n \log 2n - 3n \log 3n) - 100 \log 4n + (4n-100) \log (1 - 25/n)$.

Now, let's start rearranging, recalling that $\log 4n = \log 4 + \log n$ and so on.  You get

$\log f(n) = 4n \log 4 + 4n \log n + n \log n - 2n \log 2 - 2n \log n - 3n \log 3 - 3n \log n - 100 \log 4n + (4n-100) \log (1-25/n)$.

The terms with $\log n$ cancel out, so you get

$\log f(n) = n(4 \log 4 - 2 \log 2 - 3 \log 3) - 100 \log 4n + (4n-100) \log (1-25/n)$.

The first term grows linearly.    The second term grows logarithmically.  The third term approaches $-100$ as $n \to \infty$.  So the whole thing grows linearly as $n \to \infty$; in particular since $4 \log 4 - 2 \log 2 - 3 \log 3 = \log (256/108) > 0$, the whole thing goes to infinity, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Can you see that $(4n-100)^{4n-100} \sim (4n)^{4n}$ as $n\to \infty$?

Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(4n-100)^{4n-100}n^n}{(3n)^{3n}(2n)^{2n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(4n)^{4n}n^n}{(3n)^{3n}(2n)^{2n}}$$

Comment: By $(4n-100)^{4n-100} \sim (4n)^{4n}$, do you mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(4n-100)^{4n-100}}{(4n)^{4n}}=1$? If so, I don't see why, because $(4n)^{4n}$ is much bigger than $(4n-100)^{4n-100}$...

Comment: Yes, it is. Hints: $(4n)^{4n}=e^{4n\ln 4n}$.

Comment: So that would reduce it to showing $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}4n\ln(4n)-(4n-100)\ln(4n-100)=0$. Can't quite see why that's the case.

Comment: It's not true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (4n-100)^{4n-100} / (4n)^{4n} = 1$.  This limit is $4^{-100}$.  That being said, a constant factor won't have an effect on the limit going to infinity.

Comment: @MichaelLugo I tried WolframAlpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%284n-100%29%5E%284n-100%29%2F%284n%29%5E%284n%29+as+n+-%3E+infty), and the limit is $0$.

Comment: You're right.  That'll teach me to do tricky limits in my head.